# express jade handle helper errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Is there a way to have a custom exception handler for jade template errors?

E.g.

```
// server.js
app = express();
app.set('view engine', jade);
app.locals.js = function () { throw new Error('hello'); }

// views/index.jade
html
  != js()
```

the above will throw an error and jade will print the error when the page is loaded. It's just a simple print of the message.

I want to write my custom debug handler which, at the very least, wraps the error in a  tag so I can read it properly, but nothings seems to work as the exception is handled on the jade middleware and not passed to express (and thus not picked up by any express middleware handler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `res.render` to render the template, you can also append a callback:

```
res.render('index.jade', {}, function (err, page) {
    if (err)
        // render the error
    else
        res.end(page);
});
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more global/automated, but that also did the job nicely! Thanks